# Longest uninterrupted session in a single football game

Tags: football, trivia, records

What is the longest duration over which a football game ran in which there was no foul or ball going out of court?

Basically game went on without any interruptions.

Which game and how long was the duration?

I am interested in country vs country matches or national level club games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-longest-duration-a-ball-has-been-in-play-in-a-football-match):

> I remember this particular phase in a Premier League game involving
>   Manchester United and Blackburn which ended 1–1. Manchester United
>   played around 10 minutes(!) of uninterrupted football - aimlessly
>   passing the ball at the back as a draw was enough for them.

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=PAML9SSpILI)